# Marshaling nested structures from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I have the following types in C++:

```
typedef void* keychain_handle;

typedef struct {
  const char* keyHolderName;
  unsigned int numKeys;
  key* keys;
} key_holder;

typedef struct {
  const char* keyName;
  unsigned int keySize;
} key;
```

And I have the following methos:

```
int createKeyChain(
  int id, 
  key_holder* keyHolders,
  keychain_handle* handle);
```

I need my C# to create key holders with keys, send it to the C++ code and receive a handle.

This is my C# code:

```
    /* Structs */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Key
    {
          public string key;
          public uint size;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct KeyHolder
    {
          public string name;
          public uint keys;
          public IntPtr keys;
    }


    /* Sync API */
    [DllImport("keys.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern uint createKeyChain(uint id, KeyHolder[] keyHolders, ref IntPtr handle);


        Key[] myKeys = new Key[1];
        myKeys[0] = new Key { key = "tst", size = 5 };

        KeyHolder keyHolder = new DllWrapper.KeyHolder
        {
            name = "tst123",
            items = 1,
            keys = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Key))*myKeys.Length)
        };

        IntPtr c = new IntPtr(keyHolder.keys.ToInt32());

        for (int i = 0; i < myKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(myKeys[i], c, false);
            c = new IntPtr(c.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Key)));
        }

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(c, keyHolder.keys, false);

        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;

        var ret = createKeyChain(111, new []{keyHolder}, ref handle);
```

Everything is working well except for the internal string inside the Key object, which is corrupt. I suspect it is the StructureToPtr that is corrupting it. How can I make the string show on the C++ side?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please show what have you tried in C#?

Comment: please add `Key` and `KeyHolder` definitions

Comment: @nikis, sorry I forgot to add it, added now.

Comment: That's quite a nasty one. Going to require quite a bit of manual marshalling. I think you'll need to marshal the array of keys as `IntPtr`, and then marshal each key individually. Going to need one call to `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi` for each element of the array. Is C++/CLI an option?

Comment: Yeah I guess it is an option.

Comment: The [MarshalAs] attribute on the IntPtr is not valid, you have to delete it.  And you have to get rid of m_Keys, the *private* keyword has no effect on marshaling.

Comment: @Tsury you have declared `keys` twice in your `KeyHolder` struct, `m_keys` is redundant

Comment: Yeah I remove the problems in KeyHolder and now it works, only the strings are corrupt

Comment: The keyHolder string is fine but the inner keys strings are corrupt.

Comment: I don't think the marshaller is going to do it for you..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making changes to the unmanaged code, you have no option but to marshal this all yourself. Which looks something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct _Key
{
    public IntPtr keyName;
    public uint keySize;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct _KeyHolder
{
    public string name;
    public uint numKeys;
    public IntPtr keys;
}

public struct Key
{
    public string keyName;
    public uint keySize;
}

public static _KeyHolder CreateKeyHolder(string name, Key[] keys)
{
    _KeyHolder result;
    result.name = name;
    result.numKeys = (uint)keys.Length;
    result.keys = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(keys.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(_Key)));
    IntPtr ptr = result.keys;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.numKeys; i++)
    {
        _Key key;
        key.keyName = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(keys[i].keyName);
        key.keySize = keys[i].keySize;
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(key, ptr, false);
        ptr += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(_Key));
    }
    return result;
}

public static void DestroyKeyHolder(_KeyHolder keyHolder)
{
    IntPtr ptr = keyHolder.keys;
    for (int i = 0; i < keyHolder.numKeys; i++)
    {
        _Key key = (_Key)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(_Key));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(key.keyName);
        ptr += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(_Key));
    }
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(keyHolder.keys);
}
```

Comment: The function actually takes an array of key holders, but that's not actually the issue. The only issue I have left is the key string not making it to the C++ side. Can you give an example to what you have just explained?

Comment: I've updated my post to contain my latest code, where I iterate over all the keys and marshal them.

Comment: What you suggested regarding the Key array is not working: Cannot marshal field 'keys' of type 'KeyHolder': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination  (Arrays fields must be paired with ByValArray or SafeArray).

Comment: Ok. I deleted that. I can't write any more code right now. If you are still stuck later, I'll have time.

Comment: Well I am officially stuck. I even tried to change the string to one(!) char, and it comes out corrupt.

Comment: Apparently I can't access my computer remotely. I'll try it first thing in the morning and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You still need to tell .NET to marshal the strings as PChars:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Key
{
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public string key;
      public uint size;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct KeyHolder
{
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public string name;
      public uint keyCount;

      public Key[] keys;
}
```

Comment: Even if I add that attribute, the key string is corrupt. I think the Marshal.StructureToPtr for the entire Key object corrupts it.

Comment: @Tsury Aaah, of course, you can't do that when you're using `Marshal.StructureToPtr`. Either make the invoke work all the way through (e.g. `Key[]` instead of `IntPtr`), or handle the strings manually as well -  `IntPtr key`, and `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.

Comment: Isn't PtrToStringAnsi the opposite? I need to convert a string to IntPtr, right?

Comment: @Tsury: Oh, I thought you want to read those. If you want to pass some, `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi` is your man. Do make sure either you (usually you, right after the method call) or the library free up the memory, though.