# Sending an array in a UWP app from C# to a C++/Cx dll

Tags: c#, uwp, marshalling, c++-cx

I'm working on a UWP project. I want to send an array of position data (currently I'm just sening a float array as a test) from c# to C++ (in order to render a generated mesh in DirectX on top of XAML stuff).

I tried this: [Improper marshaling: C# array to a C++ unmanaged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309838/improper-marshaling-c-sharp-array-to-a-c-unmanaged-array) (the accepted answer). But it doesn't work, I'm guessing I'm missing something, but I don't know what. When I try what he suggests, my compiler complains about the CInput struct declared in C++, because it's native, and so it can't be a parameter in a public function. (the function that is called from c#)

(I would have commented on that question, but I don't have that privilege yet.)

This is my code:

in C#:

```
public struct CInput
{
    public IntPtr array;
}

public VideoView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;

    float[] test = new float[4];
    CInput input = new CInput();
    input.array = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<float>() * test.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(test, 0, input.array, test.Length);
    D3DPanel.CreateMesh(out input, test.Length);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(input.array);
}
```

in C++ (in D3DPanel.h):

```
struct CInput
{
    float* array;
};

[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
public ref class D3DPanel sealed : public Track3DComponent::DirectXPanelBase
{
public:
    D3DPanel();

    void CreateMesh(CInput points, int length);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I tried the PassArray pattern, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700131.aspx), but it gives this error: "Error C4400 'const int': const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported"

```
void CreateMesh(const Array<float>^ points, int length);
```

And replacing "const Array^" with "Array" gives "syntax error: identifier 'Array'".

Comment: I'm using a struct because I'm just trying to do what was written in the accepted answer. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're saying (actually, I'm sure I don't). I'll look up the types you're talking about and see if I can understand it better, and come back with new questions.

Comment: So, to use IVector I need to make a new ref class that inherits from IVector and use that instead of the CIput struct in the C++/CX part. Is that correct? So I need to implement all functions defined in IVector?

Comment: When I try to use Platform::Array, the compiler complains about it. (Error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'Array')

Comment: I tried the PassArray pattern, as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700131.aspx
but it gives this error: "Error C4400 'const int': const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported"

Comment: Wait, were did the original comment go to? (the one I replied to in my first comment here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code a little bit, as IntelliSense suggests, use

```
Platform::WriteOnlyArray<float>^
```

When it's "out" type, and

```
const Platform::Array<float>^
```

when it's "in" type.
As C++/CX does not support "in/out" type.

I suggest you do the memory allocation in C++/CX, so in your C# code, you can pass in a array directly without worrying about Marshalling.

Comment: Yes! I actually found that last friday at the end of the workday.
Turns out it's all actually simpler than I expected, I don't even need to do any marshalling. So that PassArray pattern I found does do the trick.

You say Intellisense suggests that, but my Intellisense didn't suggest a thing, it only seems to work in c#, not in C++/CX.
Which is the reason why I forgot to put that "Platform::" there (which took me hours to realize, urgh), I'm used to Intellisense fixing that for me. :s

Comment: To my surprise, I could even just make a public value struct in C++/CX, and use that type in C# directly! (Which is the type I used in my array to store all the position data.)